# Android - Facebook Login won't work in Signed Apk

Tags: android, facebook-login

I have implemented `Facebook` login in my android app.It works fine in debug mode.When i created signed `apk` I have properly used

```
keytool -exportcert -alias key0 -keystore /home/pritish/Desktop/simplypubliccloud.jks | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

and then entered my `keystore` password & have updated the `keyhash` in Facebook Developers site, still `Facebook` login won't work in signed `apk`.
I am using Ubuntu os

Comment: is there any error shows?

Comment: When i click my Login with Facebook button,it shows Error saying Invalid key hash.The key hash does not match any stored key hashes.Configure your app key hashes at https://developers.facebook.com.But i have already configured the right key hash.

Comment: Which key hash you have used? Generated using signed keystore?

Comment: @UpendraShah yes

Comment: Try this copy the keyhash from the error showing and paste it to the Facebook Console. See if error persists

Comment: key hash in error for signed apk is not available. It is available only for debug apk.I had encountered that problem for debug apk. In fact for signed apk,the key hash they specify is the one which i wrote in keyhash of facebook developers site. If they specify correct keyhash for signed apk,any user who first encounters it may tamper it.